# How do I scrape TLS certificates using go-colly?

Tags: go, ssl, web-scraping, go-colly

I am using [Colly](https://github.com/gocolly/colly) to scrape a website and I am trying to also get the TLS certificate that the site is presenting during the TLS handshake. I looked through the documentation and the response object but did not find what I was looking for.

According to the docs, I can customize some http options by [changing the default HTTP roundtripper](https://go-colly.org/docs/introduction/configuration/). I tried setting custom GetCertificate and GetClientCertificate functions, assuming that these functions would be used during the TLS handshake, but the print statements are never called.

```golang
    // Instantiate default collector
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        // Visit only domains: hackerspaces.org, wiki.hackerspaces.org
        colly.AllowedDomains("pkg.go.dev"),
    )

    c.WithTransport(&http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetCertificate: func(ch *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
                fmt.Println("~~~GETCERT CALLED~~")
                return nil, nil
            },
            GetClientCertificate: func(cri *tls.CertificateRequestInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
                fmt.Println("~~~GETCLIENTCERT CALLED~~")
                return nil, nil
            },
        },
    })
```

Please help me scrape TLS certificates using Colly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet to get leaf certificate from raw `http.Response` in case you give up getting certificate using Colly.

```
tls := ""
if res.TLS != nil && len(res.TLS.PeerCertificates) > 0 {
    cert := res.TLS.PeerCertificates[0]
    tls = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(cert.Raw)
}
```